# Algebras of monad of polynomials over commutative rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, solution-verification, monads

Consider the endofunctor
$$
\begin{align}
(-)[x] \colon \operatorname{CRing} &\to \operatorname{CRing} \\
A &\mapsto A[x].
\end{align}
$$

As explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1467500/is-polynomials-in-x-a-monad#1467526), this defines a monad over the category of commutative rings. In particular

- the unity $\eta_A \colon A \to A[x]$ is given by the canonical inclusion;
- the multiplication is given as
  $$
    \begin{align}
    \mu_A \colon A[x][x] &\to A[x] \\
    \sum_m \left (\sum_n a_{n,m} \, x^n \right) x^m &\mapsto
      \sum_{n, m} a_{n, m} \, x^{n+m}.
    \end{align}
    $$

I want to find out what is an algebra for this monad (in the linked post it is claimed that - in the case of rings - an algebra consists of a ring and an element of its center).

Following the definition, an algebra is a pair $(A, \xi)$ where

- A is a (commutative from now on) ring,
- $\xi \colon A[x] \to A$ is a ring morphism such that the square
  $\require{AMScd}$
  \begin{CD}
      A[x][x] @> T \, \xi >> A[x]\\
      @V \mu_A VV @VV \xi V\\
      A[x] @>> \xi > A
    \end{CD}
  commutes (!!! see the first comment below).

The morphism $\xi$ is determined by a ring morphism $\xi_0 \colon A \to A$ and and elment $\xi(x) \in A$ from
$$
\xi \left(\sum_n a_n x^n \right) = \sum_n \xi_0(a_n) \, \xi(x)^n.
$$

Chasing the element $(a \, x^0) \, x^0$ in the commutative square gives the identity
$$
\xi_0(a) = \xi_0(\xi_0(a))
$$
for every $a \in A$, hence $\xi_0$ is a projection (idempotent endomorphism of $A$).

Using this fact and chasing the generic element
$$
\sum_m \left (\sum_n a_{n,m} \, x^n \right) x^m
$$
in the commutative square we have

- passing through the left lower corner, the element
  $$
    \xi \left(\sum_{n, m} a_{n, m} \, x^{n+m} \right) =
    \sum_{n, m} \xi_0(a_{n, m}) \, \xi(x)^{n+m};
    $$
- passing through the right upper corner, the element
  $$
    \xi \left(\sum_m
          \left (\sum_n \xi_0(a_{n,m}) \, \xi(x)^n \right) x^m \right) =
    \sum_{n, m}
      \underbrace{\xi_0(\xi_0(a_{n, m}))}_{= \xi_0(a_{n, m})}
      \, \xi(\xi(x))^{n} \xi(x)^m.
    $$

Choosing $a_{n, m} = 1$ and $n_{\text{max}} = 1$, $m_{\text{max}} = 0$, this gives
$$\xi(x) = \xi(\xi(x))$$
ie. $\xi(x)$ is in the image of $\xi_0$.
Clearly this condition is also sufficient for the commutativity of the square.

Conclusion: an algebra for this monad consists of

- a (commutative) ring $A$,
- a morphism $\xi_0 \colon A \to A$ such that $\xi_0^2 = \xi_0$,
- an element $\xi(x) \in \operatorname{im}(\xi_0)$.

> Question 1: is the above discussion correct?
>   Question 2: is the claim in the linked post correct?
>   I must have used commutativity but I don't realize where.

Comment: I realized that I forgot about the compatibility with the unity, which gives $ \xi_0 = \xi \, \eta_A = \operatorname{id}$.

Comment: I don't think that the distinguished element has to be central in the non commutative case, but in your case since you are working on commutative rings this should not be a problem since all elements in a commutative algebra are central.

Comment: Also the thing you forgot and added int he comments drastically simplifies the rest of your discussion, rewrite the question with the fact that $\xi_0 = id$ and you will see that you awnsered your own question.